# reg-event-db - how it affects SPA load speed

Tags: re-frame

I have a question about reg-event-db - is it wise to create as much of these in our singe page app as we want? I mean - how it will affect runtime complexity of the application? Let's say that I can create 100 small reg-event-db's for my app, or one with more general purpose - is my app will load significantly slower/faster or it doesnt matter?